# Don't show the timestamp & info on iterate

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, timestamp

No idea why this is showing the entire table. Should only be showing the list and not the table (timestamp, id, etc).

[Screenshot of output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqlRc.png)

show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @application.name %></h1>
<h4><%= @application.description %></h4>
<h3>Questions</h3>
<ul>
   <%= @application.tests.each do |test| %>
      <li>
        <%= test.question %>
      </li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "tests", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "question"
 t.integer  "application_id"
 t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
 t.index ["application_id"], name: "index_tests_on_application_id", using: :btree
end
```

new to this whole "coding" thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `@application.tests.each` you are printing the return, change:

```
<%= @application.tests.each do |test| %>
```

For

```
<% @application.tests.each do |test| %>
```

Comment: If I could come through this computer and hug you, I wouldn't because of crippling anxiety over human contact but I would sure think about it. You're a hero, Alejandro.

Comment: Jajajaja, Glad I could help, please accept the answer @andywalt

Answer (score 0):

<% %> and <%= %> both execute Ruby code.

<% %> will execute Ruby code, but will not render the return value into html. <%= %> will execute Ruby code, and will render the return value into html.

So use like this :-

```html
<% @application.tests.each do |test| %>
  <li>
    <%= test.question %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```